# Authorization Required error while trying to list hotels.

Tags: httprequest, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401, booking.com-api

I'm affiliate to booking.com then I want to use Booking API docs [here](https://developers.booking.com/api/commercial/index.html?version=2.0).

The request which I'm using is this:

```
GET https://distribution-xml.booking.com/2.0/json/hotels?hotel_ids=10004
```

I have used basic authentication in my request headers

But I am getting this error :

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Authorization Required",
            "code": 401,
            "ruid": "UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YVhcDYJlWOcAkxMZH+1jcquI5Z7fv6LDYaceuj3AdKd3VDgwdChn5akQBxBnXalRCXWo+sYnzuopS7/bBrZXsHI="
        }
    ]
}
```